# getting error while performing oversample operation in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, oversampling, smote

I am working on a machine learning model(classification) where my dataset is imbalanced and i want to balance it by using oversample() function from 'imbalance' package in R.

Below are the codes used for oversampling where 'Final.Status' is my response variable and it's a factor data type.

```
training <- na.omit(training)

training.oversamp <- oversample(training,method = "SMOTE",classAttr = 'Final.Status')
```

But while doing it i am getting below error:

```
Error in dataset[, classAttr] == c : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
In which(dataset[, classAttr] == c) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.factor") for "=="
```

Also out of curiosity can anyone brief different methods used in oversample() function and which one is commonly used.

Comment: How many levels does `Final.Status` have? Morever, I think you need to define `ratio` in `oversample`. By default it is `NA`.

Comment: There are two levels,what is the purpose of ratio?
However i tried by using ratio but still i am getting same error.

Comment: From `help(oversample)`: `ratio` - Number between 0 and 1 indicating the desired ratio between minority examples and majority ones, that is, the quotient size of minority class/size of majority class. There are methods, such as ADASYN or wRACOG to which this parameter does not apply.

Comment: Can you post the result of `str(training)`?

Comment: @carlo_sguera i figured it out using different function  named `upSample()` from `caret` package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and my solution was to transform the data set from `tibble` to `data.frame`.

In your case it could be as follows:

`training.oversamp <- oversample(as.data.frame(training),method = "SMOTE",classAttr = 'Final.Status')`